# Mysql Array Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to echo out all of the user rows in my database as a select in a form.

It is only showing a blank space.  Nothing else.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../../config.php');
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$qry=("SELECT `rank`,  `uname` FROM users WHERE `uname` = '$user'");
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rank'];
$logged = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
  if ($logged == true) {
   if ($rank >= 3) {
    echo "Succesful, $user.<br />
      <form method='POST' action='delete.php'>
      <select><option>Please select</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $users = $row['uname'];
            $lol = ucwords($users);
           }
       echo "<option>$lol</option>";
       echo "</select>
    </form>";
   } else {
  echo "Your not an admin. $user";
  }
 } else {
echo "Please login.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Add tags specific to your question, maybe `php` and maybe `mysql` - database is useless to attract attention to it. PS mysql does not have arrays

Comment: @njk It not work - no understand why - refuse to google for answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First, please stop using `mysql_` functions as they are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). Look into `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Be aware that your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

The reason your script is not working is because it appears you are calling `mysql_fetch_assoc` twice. When calling it the second time, there won't be any output if your query only returns a single row.

```
$qry=("SELECT `rank`,  `uname` FROM users WHERE `uname` = '$user'");
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rank'];
```

You will need to resubmit a query (something like below) and call that result separately to populate the drop down, or store the result in an array.

```
$qry=("SELECT `uname` FROM users");
$result=mysql_query($qry);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo '<option>' . ucwords($row['uname']) . '</option>';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your while loop is set up badly, I think you need to change

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $users = $row['uname'];
  $lol = ucwords($users);
}
echo "<option>$lol</option>";
```

to this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $users = $row['uname'];
  $lol = ucwords($users);
  echo "<option>$lol</option>";
}
```

Comment: <form method='POST' action='delete.php'>
      <select><option>Please select</option></select>
    </form>

Comment: @RyanRegards Am I dyslexic or did you just not [ask the same question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756514/mysql-array-not-working) Perhaps you should look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I reread your question and it seems that you want to display all unames from your table.
The original query was to check if the user is an admin.

Here's how it will look like. But it's just a duplicate of [njk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679449/njk) [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756514/mysql-array-not-working)

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../../config.php');
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$qry=("SELECT `rank`,  `uname` FROM users WHERE `uname` = '$user'");
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rank'];
$logged = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
  if ($logged == true) {
   if ($rank >= 3) {
    echo "Succesful, $user.<br />
      <form method='POST' action='delete.php'>
      <select><option>Please select</option>";

      // added these 2 lines
      $qry=("SELECT `rank`,  `uname` FROM users");
      $result=mysql_query($qry);

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $users = $row['uname'];
            $lol = ucwords($users);
            echo "<option>$lol</option>";
           }

       echo "</select>
    </form>";
   } else {
  echo "Your not an admin. $user";
  }
 } else {
echo "Please login.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Then try running this query in your mysql console or phpmyadmin `SELECT rank, uname FROM users WHERE uname = '$user'` where $user contains anything and see if it display 2 or more rows. If it only returns once, then there's something wrong with your query in the first place.

Comment: @ace There will never be anything displayed in the OP's `while` loop if the original query only returns one row.

Comment: @njk I agree, I feel that the query is wrong because `uname` seems to be unique, and the code expects to be generate a dropdown of names.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your database has more than 1 row? You are calling the fetch 1 time so the second  time it will try to fetch the second row.

Try also running the query directly into mysql and see if you get the rows you're expecting back, may be its not returning what you expected

Comment: It works when I run it in the freaking MYSQL.  I don't understand why its not working!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!