# MySQL Rows not Displayed

Tags: php, mysql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql Array Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756514/mysql-array-not-working)

I am attempting to show every row of my mysql database colum called uname in a form option but it is only displaying a "".  Here is my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../../config.php');
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$qry=("SELECT `rank`,  `uname` FROM users WHERE `uname` = '$user'");
$result=mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rank'];
$logged = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
  if ($logged == true) {
   if ($rank >= 3) {
    echo "Succesful, $user.<br />
      <form method='POST' action='delete.php'>
      <select><option>Please select</option>";
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $users = $row['uname'];
            $lol = ucwords($users);
           }
       echo "<option>$lol</option>";
       echo "</select>
    </form>";
   } else {
  echo "Your not an admin. $user";
  }
 } else {
echo "Please login.";
}

?>
```

Comment: You [just asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756514/mysql-array-not-working).